# navigation without a map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am trying to implement the navigation stack on a custom robot without a priori static map.

Can anyone give me a guideline to do this?

I have set the static_map field to false in the Global Costmap Configuration file.

If I understand the tutorial correctly, I have to include a map node in my launch file, but I don't have one...

I am new to ROS and would appreciate any help I can get :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11256/navigation-without-a-map?/) by [gertr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1098/gertr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-09-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gertr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1098/gertr/) on 2011-09-20**:
I have tried to create an empty *.pgm file and pointing the launchfile to it, but this results in my map-server-1 process dying...

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-31**:
Do you also have the corresponding *.yaml ? (that might be the reason for it dying)
But I want to know what is the use of having a separate map if it is empty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A map is not necessary for running the navigation stack. All you need is a costmap, which can be created by [costmap_2d](http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d). You can take a look at [erratic_2dnav_local](http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/erratic_robot/trunk/erratic_navigation_apps/launch/erratic_2dnav_local.launch) for an example configuration.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5